# How can I produce some data with a specific shape?

Tags: python, math

I have a couple of images of graphs for which I'd like to synthesise the original (x,y) data. I don't have the original data, just the graphs.

Ideally I'd like to be able to approximate the shape of the curves using mathematical functions, so that I can vary the functions to produce slightly different output, and so that I can have simple reproducibility.

The first image shows a set of curves: temperature anomalies from the mean over some recent period, stretching back to 20,000 years before present. The second image shows a step function with a change at 10,000 years before present (log scale). (You'll also notice they have opposite x-axis directions).

For each of these, the eventual data I want to produce is a text file, with a temperature anomaly value for every 10 or 100 years.

Any solution is welcome.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Sorry, but what do you mean with "generating synthetic data to match"? If I understand you correctly, you want to generate the data set for a plotted graph…

Comment: If you have some sort of concrete data, this problem is doable, but if all you have are some graphs, perhaps not.

Comment: Hi @septi, yes that's exactly it. I want to also have a bit of control so that I can produce slightly different data. Hence my hope for a mathematical function to describe it. Maybe some combination of sine and cosine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've decided to answer with some details about a way to generate a curve using algebra.

For a periodic type curve, you'd use either sine or cosine, and fiddle with amplitude and frequency to match your particular situation. For example, y = A sin(2x), where the amplitude is A, and the period is related to the inner function of x (that bit inside the brackets). Try this in gnuplot:

```
A=2
f(x) = A*sin(2*x)
set xrange[-pi:pi]
plot f(x), sin(x), cos(x)
```

To change the amplitude as x changes just add a power term or exponential term of the x values to the amplitude:

```
f(x) = A*exp(0.5*x)*sin(2*x)
set xrange[-2*pi:2*pi]
plot f(x), sin(x)
# add an initial value (offset)
f(x) = 5+A*exp(0.5*x)*sin(2*x)
plot f(x), sin(x)
```

And so on.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure I fully understand your question. But what you could try to do is to digitize the data (windig works for windows and engauge for linux) and then do some data interpolation between the points.

The trivial interpolation which works almost all the time is just a straight line between two consecutive points. A more sophisticated approach is a cubic spline (for instance B-splines http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B-spline) that keep the second derivative continuous.

Comment: Thanks @rpsml, engauge looks promising. I'll try it out.

Comment: There's currently a page on wikipedia for digitising software: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Converting_scanned_graphs_to_data, from which I also tried out g3data/g3data2.